# Highcharts: Select multiple columns for a single X-Axis element

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/sgrg93/vqg2qqns/

```
states: {
  hover: {
    borderWidth: 8,
    borderColor: '#bad2f3'
  },
  select: {
    color: '#2061b6',
    borderWidth: 8,
    borderColor: '#bad2f3'
  }
}
```

In the above fiddle, on hover I am able to change border of both Tokyo and New York columns for any month. But on clicking, one out of Tokyo and New York columns get selected. Is there any way I can get both columns under a month selected just like it happens for hover?

Comment: You can catch click event on a point and then call point.update() to apply select styles. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mok2h2om/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks.. In your fiddle, is there any way I can toggle the selection? Like If I select bars for some other month, the previously selected bars should be unselected?